# Windows batch script to unzip files on Windows8/8.1

Tags: batch-file, windows-8, cmd, windows-8.1, unzip

By default, all the zipped files in Windows 8/8.1 are configured to open with the File Explorer program that the operating system has. I want to unzip all files in a certain directory and preserve the folder names when unzipped using batch script.
I know how to do this when 7-Zip installed on the machine. But how to do this on Windows 8/8.1 when no extracted software installed? I want to do this using windows script.

Comment: You can't do it in plain vanilla batch commands.  There is no zip/unzip utility.

Comment: For OS above XP 'compressed (zipped) folder' facility is available, where you right click folder and click 'send to' ->  ''compressed (zipped) folder', a zip file will be created within that folder.
Now select this zip file and right click, 'extract all' menu will be available.
If you select this, wizard will open to extract file.
I want this through Dos Prompt so that i can use it in my batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it using vbscript. Here is the code.

```
strZipFile = ""                                       'name of zip file
outFolder = ""                                       'destination folder of unzipped files

Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions
```

Fill in the appropriate names for the zip file and the output folder (must be quoted). Save the script with a vbs extension. In the batch file we can run the script with this entry: cscript //nologo scriptname.vbs

Comment: Your question states `No VBscript`.

Comment: @foxidrive: yeah but i could not find any solution using plain windows script. I modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [zipjs.com](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) utility introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f)

```
// unzips only part of the zip with given path inside
zipjs.bat unZipItem -source C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir\InzipFile -destination C:\OtherDir -keep no -force yes
zipjs.bat unZipItem -source C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir -destination C:\OtherDir
```